When I freeze the first two columns of a sheet only the first column is visible in the mobile application
Google Sheets for Android only displays the first frozen column. The second and subsequent frozen columns are not visible.
How can I unhide them?

In the mobile app frozen columns and frozen rows have a maximum display area.
Any frozen row or column content that exceeds the maximum space is hidden but can still be accessed/displayed by selecting the currently displayed row/column and then scrolling to another.
Scrolling can be done by selecting and then dragging with the mouse or using the usual navigation keys such as the arrows.
To display more frozen rows/columns simultaneously, reduce their height, or width, as applicable.
Two Columns Frozen

Max Frozen Area Size
(using default row height & column width)

